# Mirror modifier prevents me from weight painting

Tags: weight-painting, mirror, mirror-modifier

*Disclaimer: I am NOT asking how to apply a mirror modifier for weight painting.*

I have a low-poly model that I rigged and I am wondering why I can only use weight painting on half of my model, the right-side of it. I think that this is because I have a mirror modifier on the 3D object but am I supposed to apply it anywhere? I don't see such thing in the modifier window.

Another related-question: is it because my model is very low-poly that weight painting is very imprecise? I feel like I can only apply a weight to a vertex, but I saw several examples of smoother paint on low-poly models, I was wondering how.

Comment: The smoother paint on low-poly models, was that _Weight Painting_ or _Texture Painting_?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann It was weight Painting, maybe it used a gradient? I don't know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i just tried it out - and it worked exactly how i would have expected it: yes, you can just weight paint on the one side, like everything you can do only on the one side of the mirrored object. That's why it's called mirrored....you can also just change the vertices on one side...and so on.

You can apply the mirror modifier (just in object mode):
You don't need to apply the modifier, only if one side should not be mirrored anymore or you wanna change something just on one side.

[image]

Comment: "just in object mode", four words that saved me from 2 days of headache, so simple yet I always forgot this. Thank you!
PS: Do you have any thought related to my side-question?

Comment: yes, you can paint only on vertices, so the more vertices you have the more precise you can paint.

Comment: Okay! Thanks :)